# Loss of "From Clipboard..." option from "Change Picture" command in MS Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word, images, clipboard, microsoft-word-2016

I just got a new computer from my employer with **Microsoft Word Pro Plus 2016** installed. I noticed that the **"Change Picture..." options have changed** since my previous version of Word.

**The change:**

Right click image > "Change Picture..."  (top picture is old; bottom is new)

[image]

[image]

**2 Issues:**

1. Instead of a simple sub-menu appearing to the side of the right-click menu, now I get an annoying pop-up window -_-
2. Total **loss of the option to change picture from the clipboard** (i.e., the "From Clipboard..." option seen in the old version):

[image]

**Question:**

Is there a way to revert back to the old style? If not, **how do I go about changing my picture to my clipboard item in this new build?**

[This](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_powerpoint-mso_win10-mso_365hp/how-to-enable-change-picture-from-clipboard-option/59cad96d-908d-4176-b771-c700a608a905) Microsoft Forum post from 01/2018 on this very issue has not been adequately answered :(.

---

**Build Details:**

- Old: Microsoft Word 2016 MSO (16.0.10325.20082) 32-bit  [on Windows 7]
- New: Microsoft Word 2016 MSO (16.0.4639.1000) 64-bit  [on Windows 10]

Comment: I looked in the commands list. There no longer appears to be a "Change Picture >" drop down command, but simply the "Change Picture..." pop-up command. Is there a way to create the old command myself? How do I get the vba code for built-in Word commands to emulate it as a new command? though, even if I did this, could I add it as a drop-down menu item when I right-click images???

Comment: The handling of pictures in general seems to have been royally undone in Office 2016, and not only in the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

The build number of your "old" version is from July 2018 but I can't even find the build number of your "new" version ... it appears to be something before Sept. 2015. Check for updates on your "new" 64-bit version.

On the current build, the contextual right click Edit Picture menu includes the "Change Picture" option and "From Clipboard" feature.

I assume your employer supplied your former 32-bit version of Office and if that is correct, then I think someone in IT has mistakenly imaged your new system with this really old version of 64-bit Office. They should run all updates or re-image the system with the latest 64-bit version. It will have the same build number as on your former system.